# Recommendations for Lync notifiers

Tags: notification

I use Lync for Business at work. One thing I don't like about it is visually poor notification. I am using [LyncNotifier](http://lyncnotifier.com) which displays a toast notification which is much better however it has one annoying feature. The toast notification takes focus from the app I am currently using. So if I am typing away in an app and someone sends me a message, the notification takes focus and I am not typing anymore. This is a poor implementation and I find it very annoying. I have contacted them several times about this but they don't respond. Copyright on their site is 2014 which makes think they only sell the software and not support it.

Any other similar software which work better?

Comment: You can try EMClient configured with Icewarp server, its a good alternative.

Comment: We don't use Icewarp. We use Exchange.